# how to access SURFTracker Class?

Tags: surf, emgucv

I am trying to use emgu wrapper >
it contain Surf Algorithm,so i wanna know how to access surftracker class 
what's it's namespace

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.1.0.0/html/fe2edcb4-3edb-0035-7cd7-11818d7d089c.htm) says it is `Emgu.CV`

Comment: i'm trying but it is not ok >>any help plzz :(

Comment: If you want to get help, you will have to provide more details about your problem. Edit your question, add relevant info, then maybe someone will help.